# Android - How can i show more than one line in a TextView and also show it from bottom to top

Tags: android

im trying to do an application to send messages between 2 people, so i need to show a lot of text in the TextView. The problem is that i dont know how to show a lot of text from different people in a textview, also how can i make so the text can go from bottom to top instead of from top to bottom?

Comment: Didn't realize that you said textview, but yeah, this is better implemented with a ListView and alternating ArrayAdapter

Answer (score -1):

First get the current text From the text view like

```
String current = tv.getText().toString();
```

Second Append the new line to the current string lik

```
current+="\n Alice: Hello , Jim";
```

Third,Set it to the textView

```
tv.setText(current);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. singleLine = false
2. gravity= bottom

Set it to the textview , you try

other way , append "\n"  in you textstring